# SAS: Preserve leading space in macro variable resolution

Tags: sas, quoting

I am using the SAS DDE functionality to call Excel commands.  The command I'm using takes in the worksheet name.  Unfortunately, the worksheet name I am working with contains a preceding space.  Spaces can usually be handled with `%str( )`.  In this case, the quoting gets tricky:

```
%let sheet = %str( )Sheet X;
filename cmds DDE 'excel|system';

data _null_;
  file cmds;
  put '[WORKBOOK.SELECT("&sheet.")]';
run;
```

This causes an error with the DDE session. The sheet name is not resolving as intended.  I know this because the command works when the sheet is given explicitly:

```
put '[WORKBOOK.SELECT(" Sheet X")]';
```

How can I write the `put` statement such that `%let sheet = %str( )Sheet X;` resolves properly?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&sheet` with `%unquote(&sheet)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with the space, it's with the single quotes.

This works fine for me:

```
  put "[WORKBOOK.SELECT(""&sheet."")]";
```